# Make an 'or' in a if statement

Tags: php, sql, session

I am trying to create a system where depending on what user is a)logged in or b)if the username is found in the array.

If you are logged in and in the friend_array of the person, you should see the 'Unfriend' button.
If you're on the page which is your own profile, everything is hidden
If your not on your page and not in the array, 'Add Friend'.

Unfriend seems to be working, but it just seems to be defaulting 'Add Friend' whenever I' on my profile:

```
$cool = $_GET['id'];
$evan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user_login']}'");
$joe1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($evan);

$cookie = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'");
$joe = mysql_fetch_assoc($cookie);

$i = 0;
$berbs = $joe['username'];
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

if (in_array($_SESSION['user_login'], $friendArray)) {
$addAsFriend = '<input type="submit" name="removefriend" value="UnFriend">';
echo $addAsFriend;

}
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

if ($_GET['id'] == $joe1['id']) {
$addAsFriend = '<input style="display:none;" type="submit" name="addfriend" value="Add Frimm1end">';
echo $addAsFriend;

}
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

if (!in_array($joe1['username'], $friendArray) || !$_GET['id'] == $joe1['id']) {
$addAsFriend = '<input type="submit" name="addfriend" value="Add Friend">';
echo $addAsFriend;
}
```

Comment: I'm suprised it's doing anything at all with this in there `$cool = $_GET['id];`.

Comment: Make sure you don't introduce types in your example. Otherwise people keep pointing it out (unless this is what causes the problem of course).

Comment: SQL Injection like a pig...Where would it be running?

Comment: There is no need to call `error_reporting` after each line of code, is it? It is enough to call it once at the begining...

Answer (score 2):

`!$_GET['id']` will most likely always evaluate to TRUE.  The following line:

```
if (!in_array($joe1['username'], $friendArray) || !$_GET['id'] == $joe1['id'])
```

Could be read

```
if (!in_array($joe1['username'], $friendArray) || TRUE == $joe1['id'])
```

You probably want

```
if (!in_array($joe1['username'], $friendArray) || $_GET['id'] != $joe1['id'])
```

**Explanation**
PHP's dynamic type casting will take any positive integer or non-empty string and evaluate them to TRUE if you attempt a boolean expression such as `!$_GET['id']`.  You have another boolean expression testing if `TRUE == $joe1['id']`, which will always be true unless `$joe1['id']` is empty.

As a side note, you can prevent this kind of typecasting from occurring by using the Identical and Not Identical operators (=== and !==).

```
if (false == 0) {
    echo "This will be true";
}

if (true == 1) {
    echo "This will also be true";
}

if (false === 0) {
    echo "This will never echo";
}

if (true === 1) {
    echo "This will also never echo";
}
```

Comment: or to follow the OPs logic:
if (!in_array($joe1['username'], $friendArray) || !($_GET['id'] == $joe1['id']))

Comment: @MortenSickel, yes, that might be what he's looking for.  It's honestly a little hard to tell.  In either case, dynamic type casting is what's getting him stuck.